# datatables default column width not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

i've the following datatables script

```
var table = jQuery('#tb').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    colReorder: true,       
    "bSort": false,
    "pageLength": 100,
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        'colvis'
    ],
    columnDefs: [ 
        { "width": "5%", "targets": 6 }
    ]
});
```

i try make to number 7 column's width not be autowidth, the current column's data is too long and without any word wrap/break, but this part of about is not working

```
columnDefs: [ 
    { "width": "5%", "targets": 6 }
]
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var table = $('#example').removeAttr('width').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [
            { width: "5%", targets: 0 }
        ],
    } );
```

Second solution :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

   "aoColumnDefs": [
     { "sWidth": "80%", "aTargets": [1] } // 1 would be the 2nd column
   ]
} );
```